# Algorithm sorting array from closest to farthest by given number

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I trying to came up algorithm in `js` for sorting from closest to farthest by given number, for example `(number: 5.6666, array: [-1, 9, 4, 10, 11, 0])` should return `[4, 9, 10, 0, 11, -1]`.Any idea how approach to the problem? A little gotcha actually my array is array of objects and I need sort by certain key in object. In docs said, that should use `array.sort()` with compare function, but I don't understand how implement this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sort()` function of `Array` can take a function:

```
[1,2,3].sort((a, b) => /* do something */)
```

Each time, you should return a value. A negative number will mean `a` comes before `b`. A positive number means `b` comes before `a`. `0` means they are equal.

If you want distance to the number, you want the absolute value, with `Math.abs()`. Assuming the key on the object is `value`, you can put it all together:

```js
const target = 5;
const values = [{ value: -100 }, { value: 1 }, { value: 4 }, { value: 6 }, { value: 10 }];
const result = values.sort(({ value: a }, { value: b }) => 
  Math.abs(target - a) - Math.abs(target - b));

console.log(result);
```

I used some ES6 destructuring to make it a bit cleaner by pulling the `value` out in the parameters.

If you wanted to just have the values remaining (instead of the objects), you can either use `map()` after the fact (or before).

Note, in the case of 2 numbers being equidistant from the target (in my example, `4` and `6` are both `1` away from the target), you can't guarantee which will come first. If it matters to you, you'll want to add some extra logic to hand that scenario.

Comment: Thanks for such useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sort`, you can check each of their distances from your number.

```js
var num = 5.666
var arr = [-1, 9, 4, 10, 11, 0]

arr.sort(function(a, b){
    return Math.abs(num-a) - Math.abs(num-b);
});

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and get the difference of each number from the input value given

```js
var inputArray = [-1, 9, 4, 10, 11, 0],
  input = 5;

var closest = inputArray.sort(function(a, b){
    return Math.abs(input-a) - Math.abs(input-b);
});
console.log(closest);
```

Comment: how use this if I have array of objects, and need sort for example by key `num`

Comment: sort by that particular property using .map

Comment: can't I do just `array.sort(function(a.num, b.num) {...})`?

Comment: @RamzanChasygov You can. It'd be inefficient to `map()` first. Check out my answer.